# is there any way to mock an implemented class

Tags: asp.net, unit-testing, mocking, webformsmvp

I want to **unit test** a **MVP** presenter class . but its interaction to the **service** is not through interface ( it uses a concrete class ) . now I wonder is there anyway to **mock** service class without being have to change the structure ?

Comment: You jut stand in front of it and make fun of its methods and features. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way of mocking in C#/VB.NET is by overriding virtual methods with the implementation you require for a particular scenario. For that reason, an interface is the approach most commonly used as all its methods are abstract.

Is there a reason why you are reluctant to change the service dependency to an interface? An alternative is making the methods you want to test virtual, so you can override them in your mocks, but I would not recommend that, as it is a bit dirty.

The whole point of unit testing is just testing a particular unit, so having a dependency to an implementation instead of an interface really beats the point.

Comment: yes , but this is a completed project and changing the structure is not desired .

Comment: In VS 2012, you could probably use Shims: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh549175.aspx